# Android App - Turn on "Screen Cast" from ChromeCast App

Tags: android, chromecast, mirror, screencast

This is a tricky one and I am guessing it won't be answered as I am not sure its possible.  I am working on an application that the customer would like screen cast on to a large TV, with effectively "one click" in a menu on an android device (to a ChromeCast).

Scenario is 
ChromeCast in TV and on wifi (but not connected to android device).
Android application is run by user.
User hits "one click" button (which is more like two click), one to start cast device lookup, second selects device.
Mirroring occurs

That's pretty much it.  Its the same feature as the ChromeCast App "Screen Cast" functionality...to be honest we just want to turn this on from our app, instead of having to load the ChromeCast App.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ali, from my research I have concluded you are correct.  So this then moves on to is there a way to possible fire off the ChromeCast app with command line args or some other means to turn mirroring on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no API to turn mirroring on from within an app. Note that on devices such as N5, the mirroring option is also offered from the notification shade so no need to bring up the chromecast app.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The only way I have been able to acheive this is by starting the chromecast app and starting screen mirroring from there, and have my app implement a Presentation class. Even though I have been able to fully implement the ChromeCast UIButton, it doesn't work for starting screen mirroring from within the app. Probably an undocumented API or something they might add in the future, but currently I have found no way of doing it only in-app.
-edit-
Just thought I'd mention it, but a while back (after I/O 15) Google updated the available ChromeCast API's. Using a CastPresentation and the latest callbacks, it's possible to do this.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I am also working on an app which uses Presentation class to show secondary display. Do you know how I can publish app for Chrome cast? The [Developers Guide](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/developers) states that I need a sender application and a receiver application in order to publish an app for Chrome Cast.

Comment: I'm just using the default one Google provides, as I haven't been able to register my ChromeCast yet, so I just use the default appID and the default receiver. It means you can't style it (like for example the Netflix loading screen), but it works for my purposes.

Comment: So, a layout can be displayed in Chromecast using default receiver?

Comment: Yup. Even a moving layout; basically anything in your PResentation (which afaik can even be a custom Surfaceview!)